# Baggage division British Airways

Tags: luggage, british-airways

I am planning to book a business-class ticket from London to Manchester with a checked luggage allowance of 32 kg. Can I divide it into 2-3 bags with the total at or below 32 kgs?

Comment: What does the ticket say? Does it say "one bag max 32kg" or does it say only "max baggage 32kg"?

Comment: This is page fairly clear, I think?! https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials

Comment: There's a limit for individual items because it's easier for baggage handlers to handle 2 x 32 kg bags than 1 x 64 kg bag, but the airline's documentation explains it. There are also limits on number and (often) size of bags, because they don't want you turning up with 6 huge cases filled with balloons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I divide it into 2-3 bags with the total at or below 32 kgs?

That depends on how exactly the allowance on your specific ticket is formulated. You can put your specific details in here: https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/baggage-essentials

Normally business class on BA gives you 2 bags each up to 32kg, which should be plenyt.

Splitting your total weight allowance over more than the allowed number of bags depends on the airline and the mood of the check-in agent. Most European airlines will not allow it but I had good luck with SouthEast Asian airlines. You can always try to negotiate, especially if you are flying business and/or have status.

Comment: It used to be the standard in much of the world including Europe (the so-called “weight concept”, as opposed to the “piece concept” prevalent in/to/from the US and a few other places), but it seems to be going away.